# Do interjections like “but hey” have commas between them?

Tags: punctuation, commas, interjections

It seems like the correct spelling is “but, hey,” however, especially when followed by a clause, the pauses (perhaps) become excessive and the comma is frequently dropped.

For example: “But hey, at least now you know.” As opposed to, “But, hey, at least now you know.”

The question also applies to other interjections like “hey son” and “oh well.”

What is the correct usage?

Comment: _But hey_ is only used in speech, not writing. There is no punctuation (or letters) in speech. Commas are for writing, and when was the last time you wrote _But hey_ in a document?

Comment: @JohnLawler - Most frequently when transcribing speech. Like, “He told me, ‘but hey, at least it’s done now.’”

Answer (score 1):

According to [Genius](https://genius.com/The-beatles-hey-jude-lyrics), the lyrics to the Beatles' song **Hey Jude** (no comma) invariably contain a comma between 'hey' and 'Jude'.

> [Verse 1: Paul McCartney]
>
> Hey, Jude, don't make it bad
>
> Take a sad song and make it better
>
> Remember to let her into your heart
>
> Then you can start to make it better
>
> [Verse 2: Paul McCartney, John Lennon, George Harrison]
>
> Hey, Jude, don't be afraid ....

Vocatives (in the 'words of address' sense) are usually set off by a comma ("Hello, Jill." / "Let's eat, Jack." / "Hey, son, why don't you and ....")

But the no-comma version of the title strongly suggests that even this rule is not sacrosanct.

When it comes to pure pragmatic markers where a comma would not be impossible:

- Oh[,] well,
- But[,] hey,
- Ah[,] yes ...

there is a genuine choice. Ugly comma clutter in the written form and especially excessive pauses do, as you suggest, argue against the inclusion of the comma. But many would say it depends merely on whether the writer wants to signify (or the speaker used) a pause / pauses in the two-part / three-part parenthetical.

- Well, well, well

is sometimes (and probably increasingly, since the Lennon number) used without the commas.

Comment: I wouldn't trust Genius - its lyrics are all [user-submitted](https://genius.com/Genius-how-genius-works-annotated), and even if they weren't, I wouldn't expect all songwriters to know the finer details of punctuation.

Comment: @Stuart F [Lyrics.com](https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/10380606/Paul+McCartney/Hey+Jude)? If the punctuation is original, McCartney has enough clout to adjust what is considered acceptable in grey areas.